# How do I iterate over Spring Security List?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

DEBUG: This shows me all java objects:

```
<span sec:authentication="principal.usuariosGrupo" />
```

This is how im trying (store "principal.usuariosGrupo" List into "usuariosGrupo"), but no success:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.usuariosGrupo" var="usuariosGrupo" />       

<li th:each="usuario : ${usuariosGrupo}">
        <a href="#"><p th:text="${usuario.getNome()}" /></a>
</li>
```

Also tryed:

```
<a href="#"><p th:text="${usuario.nome}" /></a>
```

I feel that  `var="usuariosGrupo"` is not working.

How should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was retrieving the Spring Data by authentication class.